# Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity}; (in android 13 only)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-13

Unable to open google map in android 13, its working fine on all other android versions though.
Here is the code.

```
fun openNavigation(activity: Activity, latLng: LatLng) {
    try {
        val packageName = StringConstants.MAPS_PACKAGE_NAME
        val query = String.format(
            activity.getString(R.string.maps_navigation_query),
            latLng.latitude,
            latLng.longitude
        )
        val intent = activity.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
        intent?.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        intent?.data = Uri.parse(query)
        activity.startActivity(intent)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
W/System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the package manager to create intent for me, but i replace it with the below code and it started working fine android 13 as well.

```
activity.startActivity(
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(query)).apply {
         setPackage(StringConstants.MAPS_PACKAGE_NAME)
         }
    )
```

Basically, I created the Intent object myself.